# Return multiple values mysql without repeating values in one column

Tags: php, mysql

i have a transactions table with columns date, amount, item, list_id and i am trying to retrieve all the records into a table. But the problem is that for some items the list_id is the same since they were recorded on the same transactions and i wanted to display only unique values in the list_id column. I tried searching about `DISTINCT` but looks like all of the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959222/6240287) only retrieve one record with it and not an entire table.

So please help me out on how to fetch all records with one column with only unique values.

I was trying to retrieve them with `"SELECT * FROM expenses ORDER BY Expense_Date"`

I really do not how to represent the table structure here. Just that it has columns of date, amount, item and list_id

Comment: I get what you want to do. but I dont have any clue how to help you. There is no data, sql query youve tried. database table structure... theres nothing we can do without some information

Comment: tables please!!

Comment: @JohnRuddell, i really do not know how to represent the table structure here.

Comment: @DouglasHosea how about `GROUP BY list_id`?

Comment: Thanks @mizan3008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly need more information, but maybe a GROUP BY list_id ?